# PHP statement redirecting to "else" regardless of user input

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple login script that works with Pancake. (online invoicing)

No matter what you type in the form it redirects to the "else" statement. Rather than trying to redirect to the success page.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","example","example","example");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mypanda_clients
                              WHERE unique_id='$_POST[username]'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($_POST[password] == $ROW[passphrase])
    {
        header('Location: http://www.green-panda.com/my_panda/Clients/'.$_POST[username]); // concatenate the string
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The username and or password was incorrect. Please try again."; // missing semi colon
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: php is case sensitive. Change `$ROW[passphrase]` to `$row[passphrase]`

Comment: No. change `$ROW[passphrase]` to `$row['passphrase']`

Comment: The posted password should never match the password from the database because the database value should always be a hash. Saving passwords in plain text is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

the variable is `$row`, not `$ROW`, and you need quotes around your indexes

**From**

```
if ($_POST[password] == $ROW[passphrase])
```

**To**

```
if( $_POST[ 'password' ] == $row[ 'passphrase' ] )
```

I would also suggest to use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

the variable $ROW is not defined.

**Change**

```
if ($_POST[password] == $ROW[passphrase])
```

**To**

```
if ($_POST[password] == $row[passphrase])
```

Additionally, PHP will process your statement faster if you use quotes around your array keys:

```
if ($_POST['password'] == $row['passphrase'])
```

This is because of the way php interprets your code. It must reach the end of the text 'passphrase' before it realizes that this is not a integer based index. It then attempts to find it as a key in an associative array. This means it's effectively trying to look up `$row['passphrase']` twice before it is successful.

**Edit:**

I was slightly off here- i'm adding Philip's comment to clarify exactly why this is wrong:

*"Actually it's worse. If you had E_NOTICE on, it would warn you that it's converting an unknown constant to the string value. It's incorrect, PHP just tries to help out"*

Comment: Actually it's worse. If you had `E_NOTICE` on, it would warn you that it's converting an unknown constant to the string value. It's incorrect, PHP just tries to help out.

Comment: Good point. Just trying to make it simple to understand. Bottom line: bad idea.